# How do I properly include the Batik library in my Java project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, libraries, batik

I am trying to properly add the Batik library to my Java project. I added the unzipped binary to my lib folder:

[image: please see here]

and then tried to add the library to my project in IntelliJ through,

> File >> Project Structure >> Modules >> Dependencies >> Add (+) >>
>   JARs or directories >> [Batik directory, now in lib folder]

which led me to [image: here].

Should I just select "jar directory", or should I let all of these "roots" be added? I can see that some of them are parts of "demo" or "test" directories, so adding them specifically seems strange.

Additionally, I noticed a "docs" directory in the Batik binary folder (please see above image). Is there any way I can add Batik's documentation (Javadoc) to my IDE? If so, how?

For reference, I am using Batik 1.7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

1. Download `batik-1.7.zip` and `batik-docs-1.7.zip`.
2. Extract `batik-1.7.zip` to your module's `\lib` directory.
3. Extract `batik-docs-1.7.zip` to the `\lib\batik-1.7\docs` directory.
4. `File` >> `Project Structure` >> `Libraries` >> `New Project Library` (`+`) >> `Java`
5. Select the top-level `.jar` files in `\lib\batik-1.7` AND `\lib\batik-1.7\lib` (unfortunately, IntelliJ does not support adding `.jar` files from a directory recursively)
6. `OK` >> Select target module >> `OK` >> `Name:` `batik-1.7`
7. `Specify documentation URL` (`+`) >> `Enter documentation URL:` >> `[...]/lib/batik-1.7/docs/javadoc/` >> `OK`

Comment: I was able to get everything I wanted by importing only the batik-all jar.

Answer (score 0):

I did notice that `batik.jar` is empty (no classes) and that the docs folder does not seem to contain javadoc, so take this answer as a general recipe, you will have to adapt it. [The install instruction](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/faq.html#how-to-install) were useless to me.

As a side note, you should consider using [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or some other similar tool to manage dependencies, it will make your life easier.

---

From batik unzipped in lib:

[image: image1]

select all jar, right click and choose *Add as library*, then fill the form:

[image: image2]

then go to project structure, by right-clicking on the module (top **StackOverflow** here, see 1st image) and choose module settings (or click <kbd>F4</kbd> here **(1)**), click *Libraries* on the left and choose *batik* on the right:

[image: image3]

Now click the green + and choose *Specify documentation URL* then type the path to "docs" prefixed with "file://", here it's:

```
~/Dev/workspace-indigo/StackOverflow/lib/batik-1.7.1/docs
```

---

**(1)** could be OS / version specific.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me in figuring out the answer. `\lib\batik-1.7\docs` was useless, but fortunately Apache provides Batik 1.7 documentation for download in full. I also realized that IntelliJ doesn't add `.jar` files from a directory recursively, so `\lib\batik-1.7\lib` top-level `.jar` files have to be added to the `batik-1.7` library manually.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)